# Creating modules to be required in other files in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, module, node.js

In Node.js I can use a module like this:

```
sys = require("sys");
```

How do I create my own module like "sys" so that I can require it from other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API contains an example of writing your own module: http://nodejs.org/api.html#modules-312

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into CommonJS http://www.commonjs.org/. Node follows this protocol for require(). Some of the documentation on CommonJS describes projects that implement this in the browser.

Comment: I have looked into that site but I don't get the purpose of it. It provides modules I can use? If so, where are the modules and the API documentation? And where is the documentation for require()?